# Navicat - lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Tags: mysql, ssh, navicat

I am getting the error listed above when trying to connect to my MySQL server via SSH public key in Navicat. I have searched endlessly trying to find a solution to this. I have made sure that the AllowTCP option is enabled, and I have tried setting the hostname to localhost and 127.0.0.1 but neither of them work, it only changes the error to Connection Refused.

Here are my connection properties:

(General Tab)
Hostname/IP Address: mydomain.com
Port: 3306
Username: myusername
Password: mypassword

(SSH Tab)
Hostname/IP Address: mydomain.com (have also tried localhost/127.0.0.1)
Port: 3850 (this is the correct port)
Username: myusername
Authentication Method: Public Key
Private Key: C:\Path\To\My\Key
Passphrase: mySSHpassword

I know that probably isn't much help because there's not really any "settings" other than the ports, which I know are correct.

I am running these exact same credentials on my Macbook which runs SequelPro and it works flawlessly, so I'm lost as to why I can't get it working on my PC through Navicat.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: same issue for me, sequelPro on macbook is ok, but navicat on my win is 'lost connection to mysql server '.

Answer (score 5):

The General tab would be set to localhost (or 127.0.0.1) and the username and password would be the database credentials, not the host credentials.

Then the SSH tab would be your host with the username password you use to ssh to the host. It should be the normal ssh port 22.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'll try this solution when I get home and let you know. My SSH port is 3850 for Sequel Pro, should I still use port 22 for this?

Comment: For the SSH port you should use whatever port you'd use if you just SSH'd to the box normally. Like if you just went to a command line you would do `ssh username@host`. This by default uses port 22. If you use a different port (for example for port 2212 you would ssh with: `ssh -p2212 username@host`) then use that port.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my Navicat connected using SSH to my Rackspace MySql database from my OS X (MacBook).

The key was the settings in the General Tab. I had to set the HostName/IP to the remote name of the MySql Server.

[identifier-from-the-mysql-hostname-instance].rackspaceclouddb.com then the username and password as defined for my MySql database.

The SSH described in the prior responses, matched my settings.